# Moving element with arrow keys jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody tell me why this is not working [jsfiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/kuEA7/3/)?

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).live("keydown", KeyOperation);
});

function KeyOperation(e)
{
    alert("in");
    var top = $(".move").offset().top;
    var left = $(".move").offset().left;
    var IncrementBy = 10;

    if (e.which == 37) {
        $(".move").css({ left: left - 10 });
    }
    else if (e.which == 38) {
        $(".move").css({ top: top - IncrementBy });
    }
    else if (e.which == 39) {
        $(".move").css({ left: left + IncrementBy });
    }
    else if (e.which == 40) {
        $(".move").css({ top: top + IncrementBy });
    }
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="move"></div>​
```

CSS:

```
.move
{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}​
```

Comment: No we can't, because we don't even know what it is supposed to do... but if you explain your problem better, i.e. what you want to do and what exactly is not working, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: MY points :( please don`t downvote

Comment: Then write a good question. "Here is my code, please fix it" (and you actually did not even post the code) is *not* a good question. +0.5 for a jsfiddle, but -0.5 for not showing any effort.

Comment: Ok i will remember for future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the problem is that the element does not move (you don't really make the problem clear in your question), the reason is that the element is not positioned correctly.

Add `position: absolute` or `position: relative` to your CSS.

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuEA7/5/).

Comment: +1 nice but can i ask you to answer me in short why this css attribute here has that huge impact i mean absolute and relative to what here

Comment: perfect answer thanks and BTW Is it too hard to understand the problem from this little amount of code?

Comment: @shareef - Only elements that are positioned absolutely or relatively will respond to the `left` and `top` properties, which is what is being used here to move the element.

Comment: @KingKong - No problem, glad I could help :) It wasn't too hard to understand the problem, but you didn't make it clear what the problem actually *was*. I had to read through your code and understand what it was meant to do, but you should really have written that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `alert` function in your code, and replace the `.live` function with the `.keydown` function.